# Hard Drive Partitioning

Tags: partitioning

I have a question: Is there a "correct" way to configure the partitions on my hard drive for an Ubuntu installation?

**I have a 250GB disk and now I have the following partitions:**  (Partitions in this order on my HDD.)

- 50GB (ext4) File System Mount Point `/`
- 180GB (NTFS) Personal Files
- 4GB (SWAP)

I have a Toshiba A200-21T Laptop and I would like to have the best performance and stability possible with Ubuntu. So far, I have no grievances with the installation I have, but, I'm a new Ubuntu user and I wonder if this hard drive configuration is correct.

Thanks.

Comment: Best performance and stability are conflicting goals - you can't maximise both at the same time.

Comment: Another question: What is 'personal files', and why did you put them on a NTFS partition? Is this a dual boot system? But there you would normally have hidden recovery partitions.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's a perfect "correct" way of partitioning, it really depends on your needs.

I personally keep my swap partition near the beginning, simply so I don't need to move it if I'm extending the other partition. But that's a convenience not a performance issue.

As far as your configuration being correct, I'm not a hard drive / OS expert, but I think that's fine. I doubt changing the order would really impact your performance.

Answer (score 2):

There's no "perfect" way.

More frequently used partitions can be placed at the back end of the disk(slightly faster read speeds at the outside of the platter are possible in some instances).

Usually RAM <= Swap <= double RAM.  This is so that suspend/hibernate works as expected.

The rest of the thing is subjective and based on your use.

Examples:
A HUGE webserver for example would need a lot of space in /var.
A massively multi-user server might need a huge /home.
For simple home use, most users won't realize a lot of benefit from segregating into a bunch of partitions(completely different for servers and business users).

I, for example, put /usr/ports on a completely separate disk when running FreeBSD so I can make everything I use on most installs and move the disk about the lab/office/home and cut my compile time(must compile for generic, no optimizations, and same architecture in that case).  Anyway...Hope that makes sense.

In short, it looks like you have a reasonable setup there.